# Monitor a folder for .jpg added, autoprint using CUPS, move same .jpg to another folder

Tags: python, cups

I am trying to create an auto postcard print script on my Raspberry Pi 3B using Python 2.7. I want the script to continually run in the background checking for any new .jpg files that is dropped into the folder, autoprints ALL .jpg dropped in the folder to a printer using CUPS/pycups, and then move the .jpg to another folder called "DONE." The following code does not work: but gives a "lp: Error - unable to access "test.jpg" - No such file or directory". Appreciate any help!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cups
import os
import time
import subprocess
from glob import glob
import shutil


conn = cups.Connection()
printers = conn.getPrinters()
printer_name = printers.keys()[0]
cups.setUser('pi')

path_to_watch = ('/home/pi/Desktop/PRINT/')

source = path_to_watch
dest1 = '/home/pi/Desktop/DONE'

before = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path_to_watch)])
while 1:
    time.sleep (10)
    after = dict ([(f, None) for f in glob(path_to_watch + '*.jpg')])
    added = [f for f in after if not f in before]
    removed = [f for f in before if not f in after]
    if added:
        print "Added: ", ", ".join (added)
        subprocess.Popen(["lp", "--"] + added).communicate()
        shutil.move(source+f, dest1)
    if removed: print "Removed: ", ", ".join (removed)
    before = after
```

**EDITED:** This semi-works now thanks to @metatoaster for the printing part, but the moving to DONE folder does not work effectively. That is, when I first run the program, it does PRINT any .jpg already in the folder, then moves the .jpg files from the PRINT folder to DONE, but then when I dropped a NEW .jpg into the PRINT folder, it gives me this error, and exits the script:

```
  File "print2.py", line 30, in <module>
    shutil.move(source+f, dest1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/Desktop/PRINT//home/pi/Desktop/PRINT/test.jpg'
```

Any further advice? Thanks!

Comment: 1. Moving the files will never happen since it's outside of your `while 1` loop. 2. `files` is not defined (I assume you left out some code) 3. Have you tried printing a single file just to see if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `lp` is generating is because it can't find `test.jpg` in the current directory, which is likely the directory where you are running that Python script from. The reason for this is because the list of strings returned by `os.listdir` only has the name of the file of the directory, but not the full path itself.

```
>>> os.listdir('/tmp/foo/bar')
['file5.jpg', 'file4.jpg', 'file3.jpg', 'file2.jpg', 'file1.jpg', 'file5', 'file4', 'file3', 'file2', 'file1']
```

Note that all files are listed without the preceding dir, and not just `jpg` files like what you might want.  One possible way to fix that is to join the `path_to_watch` value for each of the values returned by `os.listdir` (so that `lp` has the full, unambiguous path to the intended file) and also filter the result by jpg, but then I noticed you have `glob` imported.  That module provides a `glob` function which should provide exactly what you need, try:

```
>>> from glob import glob
>>> glob('/tmp/foo/bar/*.jpg')
['/tmp/foo/bar/file5.jpg', '/tmp/foo/bar/file4.jpg', '/tmp/foo/bar/file3.jpg', '/tmp/foo/bar/file2.jpg', '/tmp/foo/bar/file1.jpg']
```

Note how the full path is included.  To integrate this into your code, you may want to try:

```
before = dict ([(f, None) for f in glob(path_to_watch + '*.jpg')])
```

Comment: adding in the glob(path_to_watch + '*.jpg')]) works! but I failed to have the file moved to the DONE folder after printing :( Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong with the second part or where I should be inserting that shutil code? 

`source = '/home/pi/Desktop/PRINTER/'
dest1 = '/home/pi/Desktop/OUT/'

shutil.move(source+f, dest1)`

Comment: You should be moving each individual file directly (each individual item inside `added`), use a for loop like `for source in added` and then `shutil.move(source, dest1)` inside it.